# How do I roughly cut linoleum to room width?

Tags: flooring, vinyl-flooring, linoleum

So far I had to replace linoleum twice and each time it was a room of something like slightly-more-than 3 meters by slightly-less-than 3 meters.

Linoleum is usually cut to length at a shop and then rolled up. Of course there's only a set of typical widths - and 3 meters is among those. So if a room is 3.2 meters by 2.8 meters one has to buy 3.2 meters of linoleum that is 3 meters wide and the roll is too wide for the room and won't unroll along the longer wall - it simply gets stuck. Unrolling it along the shorter wall introduces a new problem - rotating such a huge sheet without tearing it looks risky.

One solution is to cut the roll before bringing it into the room and unrolling. So far I used a plain old wood saber saw. Cuts well, rather fast and the cut is clean enough, but this just feels dumb - as if I was doing something completely wrong.

What other ways are there to conveniently cut a huge piece of linoleum to width before unrolling it?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Comment: @FreeMan This is not the case where only one proper answer is possible.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. I'd image that there _is_ more than 1 way to tackle this problem. Either the answer from Niall C. helped you enough to deserve a check-mark so others know it's useful, or it didn't and you should write and accept your own answer telling the world what you did.

Comment: @FreeMan I already explained what I did in the question.

Comment: This is a Question & _Answer_ forum. One expects to find answers in the _answer_ box, not it the question box. Plus, having a check-marked answer keeps the system from bumping this to the top of the list every few months...

Answer (score 5):

Instead of trying to work with the flooring in a cramped space, I use  a roll of craft paper and sticky tape to make a template of the room.  Start in the center of the room, lightly stick a strip to the ground, and cut it at the edges of the room.  You get a cleaner edge by going a little past the edge, then folding the cut edge back and sticking it down with the tape.  Keep sticking more strips to the template until you cover the entire room.

While you're doing that, lay the flooring out somewhere that you *do* have the space to work.  When it's ready, put the template on top of it, and cut around the edges.  Regular scissors work well for vinyl flooring, and I know I've installed real linoleum, but can't recall if scissors were OK or if I had to use something more heavy duty like tin snips.  Now that it's cut to size, you can easily carry it to where you need it and unroll it.

Comment: That is exactly how I do it also.  Only differnce is that I use red rosin paper(cause I always have a lot in stock).  I cut a few holes in the field to use tape to secure it to the floor so it won't move and tape the seems together. Then fold the edges around the room to make the template. Works fantastic. Do they still make stiff lino? lol

Comment: This is how I do it also, templateing is the way to go, lets you take your time, do it right, and you know it's going to fit when you put it in.  Only difference that I would note, is that insted of using sissors or tin-snips on the linoleum, I use a heavy duty utility knife.  Just use a stright edge and make a few passes and you are all set.